# Select the text of a TextEdit object in egui

Tags: rust, egui

Is it possible to select all of the text in a TextEdit widget upon a double-click event? I know how to detect the double-click event, I just can't see any way to select all text.

```rust
let text_edit = egui::TextEdit::singleline(&mut parameter.str_value)
.desired_width(50.0);
let output = text_edit.show(ui);
if output.response.double_clicked() {
    // What to do here?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, you can do this to select all text:

```
let mut text = String::new();
let mut output = egui::TextEdit::singleline(&mut text).show(ui);

output.state.set_ccursor_range(Some(CCursorRange::two(
    CCursor::new(0),
    CCursor::new(text.len()),
)));
```

Comment: For anyone who sees this, don't forget to do `output.state.store(ui.ctx(), output.response.id)` after or it won't work